# Selenium driver find element not working

Tags: selenium, webdriver

Selenium web driver finds element unable to find input field on the web page I tried this each and every option `XPath`, by `CSS`, by name. the testing site on the local environment.

HTML:

```
<input class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty" ng-model="email" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="username" type="text">
```

> xpath:
>
> /html/body/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/form/div[2]/div/div/input
>
> css selector:
>
> html.no-js.ng-scope body.pace-done.full-width div#wrapper
>   div.page-wrapper.white-bg.ng-scope
>   div.wrapper.wrapper-content.ng-scope div.login-bg.ng-scope
>   div.container div.row
>   div.col-sm-6.col-sm-offset-3.col-md-4.col-md-offset-4 div.login-form
>   form.ng-pristine.ng-valid div.col-sm-12.plr10px div.form-group
>   div.input-group
>   input.form-control.ng-pristine.ng-untouched.ng-valid.ng-empty

`driver.findElement(By.name("username"))`

Comment: there is no name attribute to the html you are trying to identiy, also xpath and css is too long. not a good thing.

Comment: i tired with xpath and css also but it doesn't work

Comment: It seems the application is angular. Did you handled waits correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

As per the HTML you provided, you can use the following `xpath` to identify the element-

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@ng-model='email' and @placeholder='Username']"));
```

Incase you are facing an `ElementNotVisible` exception you can induce `ExplicitWait` to wait for the element to be clickable as follows:

```
WebDriverWait wait7 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement element7 = wait7.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@ng-model='email' and @placeholder='Username']")));
element7.click();
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this should work.

```
WebElement emailInput = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[ng-model='email']")));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JavascriptExecutor je = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

WebElement Username = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@placeholder='Username' and @type='text'"]));

je.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",Username);

Username.sendKeys("Name");
```